2nd screen doesn't work anymore
this morning, after last os update (Oracle linux 9.4-1.0.6.el9.x86_64), the system don't detect anymore the 2nd display.
The monitor works fine and also the display port works, I tried with windows os that I have on the same machine.
Anyone had similarissue?
How can I detect which is the issue?
this is the output of xrandr
xxx@yyy ~]$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
   1440x1080     59.99  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     59.89  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1600x900      59.95  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77  
[xxx@yyy ~]$ 

I don't now others commands that can provide more usefull information.
Thanks,
Ciccio

for give you more info: after a reboot, I used the previous kernel and the 2nd monitor works again. So it's somthing releate to the new version

new version: 5.15.0-300.163.18.1.1.el9uek.x86_64; old version 5.15.0-210.163.7.el9uek.x86_64
